# Preventing programs from executing other programs

Tags: php, windows, linux, unix

Context: I'm wanting to write a programming competition site for our school, and I know I need to prevent file IO abuse from submitted programs.  However, what I'm wanting to find out how to do is prevent someone from writing a program that can execute other programs.  For example, someone could submit a Java program that uses the Runtime or ProcessBuilder classes to do some malicious things on our server, break the site, or mess with another competitor.

What ways are there to defend against this on unix/linux and (just for future reference) windows servers?

Comment: Have you looked into [chroot jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) ?

Comment: First and foremost, don't give them the opportunity to do it in the first place.  Run the programs in a silo on a VM with zero network and internet access.

Comment: I think your best bet is not to let untrusted entities execute code on your servers.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: How do you remotely call a program on a VM with no network access?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  @ I'll give chroot jails a look, Brandon.  @P.Brian.Mackey, that's a great idea, though I'm wondering the same thing as mellamokb. @ David Heffernan, I feel the same way, but at the same time want some kind of way to safely achieve making a competition site.

Comment: @mellamokb @DarkMatterX - Dont design a system that requires remote execution is the easiest way to avoid the problem of remote execution.  If testing and scoring are required then a better solution would be a client server relationship.  Build a Test Server that students can download from the school and run on their local machine to test their applications.  Communication can be achieved via passing of strings.  If you haven't already, look at TopCoder compeitions for some basic ideas.

Comment: @DarkMatter You can't even contemplate letting untrusted entities execute code on your servers. That's suicide. You need to find another way.

Comment: @David @P.Brian.Mackey Thanks for the warnings and I believe you both are right... So now I'm left thinking of another possible solution: Having the code somehow be tested on the client's machine instead.  Perhaps this opens up the program validation input to being unveiled with a bit of hacking by the user, but at least it won't endanger the server. Aha, maybe a client application to communicate with the server to work as the middle man...

Comment: @DarkMatterX - Test on the client.  Validate on the server (caveats above). You should not hand the real test data to the client, just give them sample sets.

Comment: You're saying to send them the input data but check their output on the server?  I see.  This still possibly exposes the input data (even with encryption and hogging the input and output (stdout and stderr) handles to the tested program on the middleman app, they could pop a GUI window or use sockets to expose the decrypted input data anyway), but at least they don't see the expected output data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real-time online programming competitions are cool...  but there are many ways to get it wrong.   I remember a Java one we used at our school that had url hacking vulnerabilities, File IO execution vulnerability, etc.  I was able to add friends from other schools and list the files on the server.  I'm surprised the system is still up.  As mentioned in the comments, you are probably better off to avoid any remote program execution of any kind.

Comment: Agreed, and at first I was thinking people probably wouldn't do anything ridiculous at our school, but that'd be a dangerous assumption to base the site on.  I shouldn't risk the server just for the idea.

Comment: For clarification for anyone seeing this later on and wondering what solution I decided to go with, I'm going to try to use an application to act as the middle-man between the client and server for doing program validation (compiling on the server and then downloading exe's or .class files to the client (if compilation succeeds), then testing on the client, then sending results to the server, then displaying results on the site. Messy, but maybe it'll work).  I'm considering trying out Java Web Start for the purpose of the middle man, but I'll have to look into properly escaping the sandbox.

Comment: @DarkMatterX: You could make the "client" a VM that is reset back to a clean, base snapshot after each run.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org) or [Apparmor](https://apparmor.wiki.kernel.org) to achieve this.

Comment: These look like they may be a great help to what I need! Thanks, I'll read up on them.

Answer (score 3):

In case for Java, you can use [security policies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) to achieve it, or at least parts of it. (Chroot jails, as suggested in a comment, are always a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  That looks pretty interesting, I'll try to look into it.